# How do I get the max value of COUNT(*) from GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have this query

```
SELECT Pname, COUNT(*) AS Num
FROM employee
JOIN project
  ON Dno = Dnum
GROUP BY Pname
```

which provides these results:

```
Pname                   Num
Computerization         3
DatabaseSystems         8
InkjetPrinters          10
LaserPrinters           10
Middleware              8
Newbenefits             3
OperatingSystems        8
ProductX                4
ProductY                4
ProductZ                4
Reorganization          1
```

**How do I query `Pname` and `Num` such that it returns the element names with the highest count?**

The results should look like this:

```
InkjetPrinters  10
LaserPrinters   10
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: My own on localhost. Idk

Comment: SQL on Xampp. Problem is solved now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HAVING clause specified from a sub query.

In MySQL

```
 SELECT Pname, COUNT(*) AS Num
 FROM employee
 JOIN project
   ON Dno = Dnum
 GROUP BY Pname
 HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM employee
  JOIN project
   ON Dno = Dnum
  GROUP BY Pname
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
 )
```

Comment: SELECT Pname, COUNT(*) AS num FROM employee, project WHERE Dno = Dnum GROUP BY Pname HAVING NUM = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM employee JOIN project ON Dno = Dnum GROUP BY Pname ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
It works! Thanks

Comment: @user3436529 if this works for you, please don't hesitate to  accept it. There are a number of users who don't read the whole post but just find the marked answer. If no answer is marked, they simply leave the post.